# How would I call a Binary Search function to run?

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

I am learning C at the moment and was given this code in a book for doing a binary search. I am still very confused on calling a C function with arguments and the book so far hasn't given me much context. I believe the 3rd argument is memory storage (i'm not entirely sure). I tried google/bing but many examples have a main function along with another function which is being called in by main. What am I missing? I tried to call binsearch like I do in Python but i've gotten a bunch of errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */

int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n -1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high)/ 2;
        if (x < v[mid]){
            high = mid -1;
        }
        else if (x > v[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            // found match
            return mid;
        }
        // no match
        return -1;
    }

}

binsearch(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your call to `binsearch()` at the end of your code needs to be in a `main()` function, just like every one of the examples you've read. C isn't Python, and the syntax is not the same. I'd suggest you go back and start over with your book, because you've not picked up the most basic parts of the language yet. If the book hasn't given you the necessary context earlier, find a new book.

Comment: You're probably better off finding a more beginners level book, or online resource.  But the main function is the entry point into the program, every stand alone executable needs to have it (a library doesn't have it). So you need to put your bin search call inside a main function.

Comment: With `3` instead of `10`, define the array as e.g. `int v[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };` and search it  for `x` like `int found = binsearch(x, v, 3);` which must be inside a function, perhaps `main`.

Comment: I'm using C ansi (I think it's beginner). I'm on chp 3 but next chapter goes more into the functions. Thank you so much for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to do something like this. But as comments recommends, (even though it is easy to skip ahead when we already know some other language) please go back and make sure you pick up the basics of C first.

```
int main(){
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int index=binsearch(4,arr,8);   
    printf("Found at index: %d",index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run C program or C project, you must have a main function or main file.

Try to compile and run code

```html
#include <stdio.h>

/* binsearch: find x in v[0] <= v[1] <= ... <= v[n-1] */

int binsearch(int x, int v[], int n)
{
    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = n -1;
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high)/ 2;
        if (x < v[mid]){
            high = mid -1;
        }
        else if (x > v[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            // found match
            return mid;
        }
        // no match
        return -1;
    }

}
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
  int re = binsearch(4,a,8);
  printf("re = %d\n", re);
  return 0;
}
```

[This the output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONDeD.png)

Comment: I change the code, and you can try this time. Actually if you know this is a bug, I think u are sure to know how to run C program.